# Really need help Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

i have been stuck in this part of a simple javafx program and i cant see what the problem is. All i am trying to do is to switch scenes while pressing a button from index.fxml to deposite.fxml i do understand that it is a thread related issue and that i am probably trying to run something at the same time. but i cant figure out where. it has been 3 days and i have been reading all post regarding this but yet i cant find the issue. Sorry if this is some kind of duplicate or anything but its driving me crazy.

main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/index.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    */


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/index.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } 
}
```

indexController.java

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class indexController implements Initializable {



    @FXML private Button makeDeposite;


    public void changeScreenButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
    {


        Parent depositeView = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/deposite.fxml"));
        Scene depositeViewScene = new Scene(depositeView);

        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        window.setScene(depositeViewScene);
        window.show();

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        System.out.println("user");

    }


}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at controller.indexController.changeScreenButtonPushed(indexController.java:28)
... 58 more
```

deposite.fxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <bottom>
      <TableView BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="57.0" text="UserID" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="108.0" text="FirstName" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="120.0" text="LastName" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="65.0" text="Age" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="183.0" text="Street" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="124.0" text="Number" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="142.0" text="Zipcode" />
        </columns>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets top="200.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </TableView>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <HBox spacing="20.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField />
                  <TextField />
                  <TextField />
                  <TextField />
                  <TextField />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="162.0" text="Button" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="100.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

index.fxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.indexController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" fillWidth="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="20.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="makeDeposite" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeScreenButtonPushed" text="Make a Deposite">
               <rotationAxis>
                  <Point3D />
               </rotationAxis>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Make a Withdraw">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Make a Purchase">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Statement" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53408309/edit) your code and add the complete stacktrace of your exception. And in order to be complete, add your FXML files (index.fxml and deposite.fxml).

Comment: code added plus fxml

Comment: Your FXML file `deposit.fxml` is not placed in your controller package where is your `indexController`. The solution below should work, or change this line `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/deposite.fxml"));` by this one `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/deposite.fxml"));`

Comment: thx for expalining the real reason i had no idea that this was why. and it did work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change `getClass().getResource` to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource`

Comment: Thx alot you saved me